# scale factor must be 1D or 3D

Tags: matlab

I'm beginner in Matlab and I'm trying to make transformation structure using `makehgtform` in imresize3d.m, but it gave me a problem:

```
Error using makehgtform (line 100)
Scale factors must be either 1D or 3D
```

what is that mean? 
The `imresize3d` is a function inside the `ASM_MakeAppearanceModel`, and the variable for scale is 5 with `double` type. And it gave me error like below.

```
Error in imresize3d (line 28)
```

code :
    `T = makehgtform('scale',scale);`

I need help with this, I'm trying to search how to solve this problem but I can't found it.

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot replicate this error using your stated inputs - try that line yourself on the command line, if scale is a double it works fine. Check that the variable "scale" isn't being overwritten elsewhere before it gets to makehgtform.  For example use "dbstop if error" and then see what happens when you re-run imresize3d.m

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not used Matlab before, I have worked with graphics libraries.

Usually with scaling transformations, either a unified scale is applied in all 3 dimensions (5, 5, 5) or a different scale is applied for each dimension (3, 5, 2).

Following this, the 1D or 3D request would therefore most likely be a request for a single number (for the first type of scaling), or for 3 numbers (for the second type of scaling).

Given the type of method, it appears only 1 value can be given for the second parameter which leads me to believe maybe an array is expected?

So instead of simply inputting your number, try inputting your number in an array.

makehgtform('scale', [3]);

If this doesn't work, maybe your input type isn't accepted? I would try a float, this is often the most supported decimal supporting numeric type.